# How do I download a 3rd party python module and integrate it with my python

Tags: python, api, module, bitcoin, blockchain

I would like to be able to use the services that the Blockcypher module provides for my programme, however i have (at least i think) downloaded the correct module package but cant get it to integrate with my Python on my Computer. I am fairly new to python so I have no idea on where to even start tackling this problem.

Comment: Consider using [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/), which is a package manager for modules; after installing a module with it then generally all that is needed is `import module` to integrate it within your script.

Comment: Please specify exactly what module it is and from where you have downloaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modules, regardless of where you've got hold of them, will be searched for in the `sys.path`. If nothing is found there, they will be looked up in the current directory.

When you download some code directly it will be a good first guess to place it in the directory of the script from where you are using the download. If it's just a `.py`-file, place it there. If it's an archive with a directory, then place the directory there (not the files).

Generally, you should prefer installing modules via a package manager such as `pip` or `conda`. Such package managers take care of placing modules properly for usage with your Python installation from wherever you will write your script. They also provide support for updating these modules to newer versions later.

Update: If you cannot make anything from this remarks, you should first read the [section on modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#modules) in the Python tutorial, or even work thru the full tutorial or [thru a good book](http://www.diveintopython.net) (or [any other](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntroductoryBooks) ;) to get a smooth entry into the friendly world of Python programming.

---

Update (2023): The Dive Into Python link above is outdated, so here is the updated link to this great resource:
https://diveintopython3.problemsolving.io
I think it's still the best beginner's resource, but, well, here are many more:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntroductoryBooks